# Formula to compute the between group sum of squares in R

Tags: r

Can anyone tell me how to code the SS between in R
to compute by hand, it is ∑ ni(meanXi - the grand mean)2

thanks,
lp

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a vector of values `x` and the mean in `x_mean`, you can compute the SS error manually simply like this:

```
> x=c(1,2,3,4,5)
> x_mean = mean(x)
> x-x_mean
[1] -2 -1  0  1  2
> (x-x_mean)^2
[1] 4 1 0 1 4
> sum((x-x_mean)^2)
[1] 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is what you want, but

```
#  create sample dataset: 5 groups, 10 values per group
set.seed(1)
df   <- data.frame(group=rep(LETTERS[1:5],each=10),value=rnorm(50))
# calculate between-group sum of squares (SSB)
sum((aggregate(value~group,df,mean)$value-mean(df$value))^2)
# [1] 0.07938908
```

This calculates the mean by group using `aggregate(...)` and then sums the squared difference between that and the grand mean (`mean(df$value)`).